# Adding a comma in between every " " to a file

Tags: awk

Input:
 `"stuff blah mostuff" "stuff and blahagain" "stuff yeablah"`

Desired output: `"stuff blah mostuff","stuff and blahagain","stuff yeablah"`

How do I do this with awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'" "' -v OFS='","' '{$1=$1}1' file
"stuff blah mostuff","stuff and blahagain","stuff yeablah"
```

but since this is a simple subsitution on a single line, it's more suited to sed than awk:

```
$ sed -r 's/("[^"]+") /\1,/g' file
"stuff blah mostuff","stuff and blahagain","stuff yeablah"

$ sed -r 's/" "/","/g' file
"stuff blah mostuff","stuff and blahagain","stuff yeablah"
```

If your real-world data is more complicated than you have shown (e.g. can have embedded escaped quotes or different spacing between strings or embedded newlines or a string containing just a blank char or...) then edit your question to show some truly representative input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `" "` with `","`

```
$ echo '"stuff blah mostuff" "stuff and blahagain" "stuff yeablah"' | awk '{gsub(/" "/,"\",\"")}1'
"stuff blah mostuff","stuff and blahagain","stuff yeablah"
```

Through sed,

```
$ echo '"stuff blah mostuff" "stuff and blahagain" "stuff yeablah"' | sed 's/"[[:blank:]]"/","/g'
"stuff blah mostuff","stuff and blahagain","stuff yeablah"
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach,

```
awk -F\" -v OFS=\" '{for (i=3; i<=NF-2; i+=2) $i=","}1' file
```